# How to find StringName(Number) in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have data in notepad++ as

```
VARCHAR(123)
```

I need to find **VARCHAR(any number)** so that i could replace it as per my requirements

Do we have any regular expression to find this?

Comment: Does `VARCHAR\(\d+\)` work?

Comment: What is your replacement logic?  Can you show us sample data?

Comment: lets say i have data like 

VARCHAR(123)
VARCHAR(213)
VARCHAR(2)

i need to replace all these with a fixed value 
VARCHAR(100)

this is just any example

Comment: Thats working :) thanks @knut

Comment: I made an answer of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
VARCHAR\(\d+\)
```

If you need the number for your replacement, then you can catch the number for the next steps:

```
VARCHAR\((\d+)\)
```